# Rename Folder in blob storage by using Azure Datalake Gen2 Rest API web activity Azure Data Facotry

Tags: azure-data-factory, rest, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using ADF Web Activity to rename a directory through the REST API  ADLS Gen2.
I tried to follow this [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create).
Here is the need : Rename folder1 by folder2 using a web activity on azure data factory.

[Rename folder1 by folder2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QhJJ.png)
And here is my json web activity definition :

{
"name": "Pipeline 1",
"properties": {
"activities": [
{
"name": "Rename Folder Activity",
"type": "WebActivity",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
"timeout": "7.00:00:00",
"retry": 0,
"retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
"secureOutput": false,
"secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
"url": "https://######*******######.dfs.core.windows.net/data/Folder2",
"connectVia": {
"referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
"type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
},
"method": "PUT",
"headers": {
"x-ms-rename-source": "data/Folder1"
},
"authentication": {
"type": "MSI",
"resource": "https://storage.azure.com/"
}
}
}
],
"annotations": []
}
}

and the encoutered error is :
[image: this one]

Comment: Please make sure to add the last part of your question in a quotation for a better reading experience by others. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: COuld you please tell me how you define the request?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the x-ms-rename-source with a slash? So '/data/Folder1' ?